# How to avoid a th element from inheriting properties from a tr element in IE6/7

Tags: html, cross-browser, css

I've got a table which has a repeating background image on the header:

```
thead tr
{
   border-collapse:collapse;
   background: #D3D2D2 url(images/background-table-header.gif) repeat-x top;
}
```

And this works across in both Firefox and Internet explorer, but if we want certain column headers to show the sorting direction we decorate the th with the class Sorted and the Direction. And use css to to add a direction icon.

```
  thead th.Sorted
  {
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center left;  
     padding-left: 0.6em;   
  }
  thead th.Sorted.Ascending
  {
     background-image: url(images/background-table-sorted-column-ascending.gif);
  }
  thead th.Sorted.Descending
  {
     background-image: url(images/background-table-sorted-column-descending.gif);
  }
```

The problem is that in Internet Explorer 6 and 7 the background-color from the tr is inherited (found out using Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar) to the th. Which means the th paints `#D3D2D2` color over the tr background. Firefox, Chrome and IE8 do not have this problem, so it's a IE6/7 bug I suspect. I thought about using a `background-color:transparant` on the `thead th.Sorted` but IE6/7 just paints the body background (it looks like it cuts a hole in the other layers between the body and the th).

This is how it should look like:

[image: correct interpretation of the css/html]

And this is how it looks like in IE6 and IE7:

[image: IE6 and IE7 wrong rendering]

Below is the HTML snipppet I created for this question.

```
  <table cellspacing='0'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First column</th>
        <th>Second column</th>
        <th class="Sorted Ascending">Third column</th>
        <th>Fourth column</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems IE has a bug - it renders the `tr`'s background image as the cell's background image, so the cell's image overrides the row's image. The same bug exists for the `thead` element, but it seems to work well with the table element.
So, you can apply your background image to the table instead of the header row:

```
table
{
   background: #D3D2D2 url(images/background-table-header.gif) repeat-x top;
}
```

Because the background image is on the table it may extend beyond the header row, so you may also want to set the background color of the `tbody` or its `tr`s:

```
tbody
{
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is odd... because this works just fine (though I am not using images, it should be the same no?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    thead tr{
        background-color:#000;
                    color: #fff;
    }
    th.sorted.Ascending{
        background-color:#fff;
                    color: #000;
    }
    th.sorted.Descending{
        background-color:#AAA;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First column</th>
            <th>Second column</th>
            <th class="Sorted Ascending">Third column</th>
            <th>Fourth column</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

//Edit//
You might want to do this instead:

```
background: #FFFFFF url(http://www.tizag.com/pics/cssT/smallPic.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not the problem I have, the problem is that I don't want to have a new background color for the th's I just want to have a small icon on the left side and just be transparent. Because the tr beneath it already has a background image repeated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in IE.
I tried it without background image for the cell:

```
thead tr
{
   border-collapse:collapse;
   background-image:url(http://www.freefoto.com/images/1223/09/1223_09_1---Big-Blue-Sky--Montana--USA_web.jpg);
   background-color:gray;
}

  thead th.Sorted
  {
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center left; /** this line changes the position! */  
     padding-left: 0.6em;   
  }
```

, and the backround image is repositioned on that cell! I guess IE renders the row's background one cell at a time.
You'd may have to add another element in the cell for that.

---

Ok, Another idea:
It seems to be working ok if you put the background image on the `table` element. `thead` is also buggy. you can try including them both (table and tr), by adding the rule:

```
table
{
   background: #D3D2D2 url(images/background-table-header.gif) repeat-x top;
}
```

Comment: Yes, IE and FF both draw the background per cell (set cellpadding to 5 and you'll see) but in your the problem remains, why does th inherits the tr background-image ? You're proposing a extra element in side of the th just to be able to set the background on that? I hope to avoid those kind of solutions, but I'll try it..

Comment: I know, my code doesn't solve this. It's a sample of the bug(?). The cell's parent's background image is moved, even though the cell has no image.

Comment: You're right I just wanted to make clear the the fact that it does render per cell is not the problem, but when deciding what to render for the cell it uses the wrong logic. And your sample indeed showed another way to reproduce this bug.

Comment: You're solution with the table background indeed works and is much cleaner than adding a extra component. I would suggest splitting that answer to a separate answer and explain how it works and that the tbody tr should probably have a background-color: #fff;. So create a nice answer out of your suggestion so google users could find it, and I'll accept it as a answer.